# Google Drive Rest Api Files export limitation

Tags: rest, google-drive-api

I use rest api "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/export" "[reference page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)" to get google Doc

I have document size ~ 5 MB when i try to get the file i had the json error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "exportSizeLimitExceeded",
        "message": "This file is too large to be exported."
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "This file is too large to be exported."
  }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: Hmm Google Docs does not have a file limit, therefore is your fileID correct and are you trying to export a Google Doc,Sheets or Slide?

Comment: yes, for doc files < 5 MB it work but the problem in files > 5 MB.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of using this export endpoint you can request `exportLinks` field in the [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list):

```sh
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?fields=exportLinks' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

That will return something like this (these are links I got for a Google Slides presentation):

```js
{
 "exportLinks": {
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=odp",
  "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=pdf",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=pptx",
  "text/plain": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=txt"
 }
}
```

And those urls don't have such a hard size limit (I was able to get out ~50mb PDFs)

Comment: Tested this solution and it works, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to get the size of pdf file while downloading to show a progress state? These links do got give a `content-length` header in the response.

Comment: @dhruv2204 haven't looked into that myself, but that would be nice. If you find a solution, please add another comment with what worked for you

Comment: There was no way to do this so I ended up showing the bytes downloaded in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error message there is a limit to how big of a file the API can export.   There is really nothing you can do to fix that your going to have to do it with smaller files.

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "exportSizeLimitExceeded",
"message": "This file is too large to be exported."
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "This file is too large to be exported."
}
}
```

Comment: @Dalm To, thanks for answer, i found this solution " https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/ " and there is no export limitation.

Comment: Thats great.  I have contacted Google to have the file limit noted so that no one else has this problem.