# Is there any way download bigger than 10MB documents using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to download bigger than 10MB **.doc** files using Google Drive API.
I know difference between export and download when using Google Drive API. I can download  files which has binary content(no limit). I should use **export** for downloading **.doc** files but there is a limit (10MB). My files larger than 10MB. Is there any way i can download .doc files using download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59168288/7415597)

It basically comes down to fetching the file's exportLinks property from calling [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) with `?fields=exportLinks`.
This will give you a bunch of exportLinks for each possibly export mimetype. This has no file size limit.

The base URL for that is usually the same so I've just saved them as constants.

```bsh
# Example of implementation
switch ($fileMetadata.mimetype) {
    'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' {
        $exportBaseUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id="
        $exportBaseUrlExtension = "&exportFormat=xlsx"
    }
}

$uri = "$exportBaseUrl$itemId$exportBaseUrlExtension"

# Now you can make a call to
```

See the [Files: overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) reference for more information

Answer (score 0):

if you check the documentation [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

[image]

it clearly states that the limit its 10 MB.  If this is a documented limit then it would suggest that this is in fact the hard limit set by google.  I suggest you submit a feature request asking to be able to upload larger files [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can't i make any trick ? Like after upload file to Google Drive, converting **.doc file** to **.txt(binary content)** formating. After that can't i download as  binary content ?

Comment: Google is very good at preventing "tricks" invented by third party developers.   If you want to try and work out a trick go for it.  I would suggest that your binary converting will be very tricky

Comment: Can I export more than 10MB, is there any paid version of API, or any other way to do so.