# C# Server downloads the file and transfers it to the user at the same time. Download fails [Google Drive]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, download, stream, google-drive-api

I'm writing a program with ASP.NET Core.

The program will download the file from Google Drive without storing it in Memory or disk and transfer it to the user.

Download function in Google Drive official libraries does not continue until the download has finished. For this reason, I send a normal `GET` request to the API and read the file as a stream and return to the user.

But after a certain size, downloading in programs like IDM or browser results in an error.

In short, I want to make a program that uses the server as a bridge, and it should not be interrupted.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Download([FromQuery(Name = "file")] string fileid)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileid))
        {
         
           
          
            var decoded = Base64.Base64Decode(fileid);
            var file = DriveAPI.service.Files.Get(decoded);
            file.SupportsAllDrives = true;
            file.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
           
            var fileinf = file.Execute();
            var filesize = fileinf.FileSize;

            var cli = new HttpClient(DriveAPI.service.HttpClient.MessageHandler);
            //var req = await cli.SendAsync(file.CreateRequest());

            var req = await cli.GetAsync($"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{decoded}?alt=media", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

            //var req = await DriveAPI.service.HttpClient.GetAsync($"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{decoded}?alt=media", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            var contenttype = req.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;

            if (contenttype == "application/json")
            {
                var message = JObject.Parse(req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).SelectToken("error.message");

                if (message.ToString() == "The download quota for this file has been exceeded")
                {
                    throw new Exception("Google Drive Günlük İndirme Kotası Aşıldı. Lütfen 24-48 Saat Sonra Tekrar Deneyin.");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(message.ToString());
                }
            }
            else 
            {
               
                return File(req.Content.ReadAsStream(), contenttype, fileinf.OriginalFilename, false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Some errors are written to the log file when downloading:

> Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection.

etc.

If user is using IDM, the error is:

> Server sent wrong answer on restart command

If user is downloading from browser, the error is:

> Network Error

I started a 1.5Gb file download with 8 mbps internet when approximate download size is 900Mb, IDM stopped download with said error.

I have no idea other than returning `FileStreamResult` in ASP.NET Core - how to download concurrent files?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried.  We need to see your code here not on a third party site. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  and describe what is not working with your current solution?

Comment: Edited Post Thanks

Comment: You **Must NOT** Capitalize Almost Every Single Word In Your English Text!

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge of English is not very good.

Comment: Have you tried having your method return File(stream, "application/octet-stream"); ?

Comment: yes i tried again but it didn't work.

Comment: You say the problem is the file size? Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890534/google-drive-rest-api-files-export-limitation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55274737/is-there-any-way-download-bigger-than-10mb-documents-using-google-drive-api).

Comment: the problem is an interruption in downloading the file.
I have to transfer the file in pieces to the user.
Thus, the download will not be interrupted and the download will be faster.