# Is there a way to export large google docs as pdfs?

Tags: google-drive-api

When exporting a large google doc as a pdf I am experiencing a timeout issue. I am currently using this [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export). Is there a way to allow me to export larger documents? Maybe there is a way to change the timeout duration or upgrade to a paid version in the [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

Use `exportLinks` instead under [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) instead as [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) does have a limit of 10mb.

#### Sample:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?fields=exportLinks&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

And it will provide you an output that contains all possible export links available (that doesn't have a file size limit)

#### Output:

```
{
 "exportLinks": {
  "application/rtf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=rtf&resourcekey=[RESOURCE_KEY]",
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=odt&resourcekey=[RESOURCE_KEY]",
  "text/html": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=html&resourcekey=[RESOURCE_KEY]",
  "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=pdf&resourcekey=[RESOURCE_KEY]",
  "application/epub+zip": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=epub&resourcekey=[RESOURCE_KEY]",
  "application/zip": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=zip&resourcekey=[RESOURCE_KEY]",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=docx&resourcekey=[RESOURCE_KEY]",
  "text/plain": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=[FILE_ID]&exportFormat=txt&resourcekey=[RESOURCE_KEY]"
}
```

#### Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59168288/14606045

Comment: If I am using the OAuth Client ID or Service Account credentials and don't have an API_KEY how should I hit the returned URL? Would passing my ACCESS_TOKEN work? To get the URLs I am using `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[FILE_ID]?fields=exportLinks`. Also I am looking for the base64 encoding of the pdf like the one the export API returns.

Comment: @ZacSchulwolf, reference wasn't passing any api_key so that should be doable. as for the encoding, that I am not sure but you can check the output by trying the [api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get). I tried the `exportLinks` and so far, no unfamiliar characters were shown

Comment: @ZacSchulwolf, If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)