# Google Drive API - Unable to export large file

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using google API to get content from gdoc file. I can't get content without exporting it. So, I am exporting into "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" mimetype to get content of file.

Here is the code to export the file:

```
$files = $service->files->export(
    $fileId,
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    [
        'alt' => 'media',
    ]
);
```

If Gdoc size is more than 10 mb and tries to export files via google API. It's throwing below error message.

```
{\"error\": {\"errors\": [ \"domain\": \"global\", \"reason\": \"exportSizeLimitExceeded\",\"message\": \"This file is too large to be exported.\"   } ], \"code\": 403, "message\": \"This file is too large to be exported.\"}"}
```

I have used this library:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export), I can't export more than 10 mb.

Is there any way to export a file that contains more than 10MB size via Google API call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive Rest Api Files export limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890534/google-drive-rest-api-files-export-limitation)

Comment: @AdrianEdelen, No, It doesn't answer my question. I get a google drive export link. But, I am not able to read content from a file using that link. I want to get content from Gdoc via API call.