# Error in exporting large files using Google Drive API v3 due to recent changes in Google Document export (images as base64 encoded image blobs)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently facing an issue with exporting files using the Google Drive API v3. Previously, I was able to download Google documents with image references only. However, the recent update has changed the format, and now the images are in the form of base64 encoded image blobs within the URL. As a result, the file size has increased significantly, leading to the following error message:

Error:
"""https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{file_id}/export?mimeType=text%2Fhtml returned "This file is too large to be exported.". Details: "[{'message': 'This file is too large to be exported.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'exportSizeLimitExceeded'}]">"""

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to overcome this problem. Is there a way to export the file successfully despite its large size? I would be grateful for any alternative approaches or workarounds that could help me achieve my goal.

Thank you in advance for your assistance and support.

Best regards,

Marco

Comment: From your question, I guessed that you are trying to a Google Document using Drive API with a script. If my understanding is correct, when you manually export it, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59168288/8016720